Displaying figure in Jupyter in PyCharm hides text ouput
When I show Matplotlib plot and after that I print the text in a Jupyter notebook, I just see an empty text block.

Everything printed before the first plot works. When I comment out the show line (either display(fig) or plt.show()), all the text outputs as usual. I also just updated to PyCharm 2024.1 and I didn't get that issue before.
I tried restarting kernel, it didn't work. I also tried to open the Jupyter notebook in the browser and it worked without any issue. Does anyone have the same issue and is there anything that solves it?
(matplotlib v.3.7.0, matplotlib-inline v. 0.1.6)

You shouldn't just share a screenshot of a portion of things. Please share code as text of a reproducible minimal example and then maybe more the example. My guess is you are mixing print() and display() , but how are we to know? Is it the text being dark and not showing on dark? And did you also try this in vanilla Jupyter to see if it is just your IDE or not? You can go here, click 'launch binder', and try your minimal reproducible example to see. If it happens in Jupyter, too, then I suspect I can tell  you at least workaround.

Reference for the mention of screenshot being insufficient: How do I ask a good question?, in particular the section 'Help others reproduce the problem' where it stresses a minimal reproducible example and not sharing a screenshots. In your case, since this a behavior, a screenshot in addition to your description is good. However, it should be more informative than what you've provided this far.

@Wayne As I wrote, I tried to open the Jupyter notebook in the browser and it worked without any issue, that's why I think there is issue inside new Pycharm somewhere and that's why I didn't put any code. Also because I tried to put the print() anywhere in the code and it doesn't change anything. The only thing that solves it is deleting the display() command and then the text appears (but of course no plot then). I have checked and there is indeed no text to select, just empty text block of the size. I'm sorry I cannot share any more of the screenshot or code due to copyright issues.
